# What is the RKUIManager?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I get an error with RKUIManager, or more precisely:

```
Could not invoke RKUIManager.manageChildren
```

It appears for example when I'm using firebase with React Native and try to set a reference in the constructor of a component with a prop. For ex:

```
messagesRef = FBRef.child("Messages").child(this.props.currentMeetingID)
```

If I change it to the following it works, and yes, I have checked if this.props.currentMeetingID is a legitimate value.

```
messagesRef = FBRef.child("Messages").child("123456789")
```

I can't seem to locate the problem nor reproduce it perfectly. I'm just trying to figure out if it's my machine or some kind of bug elsewhere.

Right now I'm just looking for info about what RKUIManager actually is.

Comment: Doesn't sound like it's part of the Firebase SDK. Maybe something on the RN side?

Comment: I got the same issue because i forgott to Import - Images - from react-native while i tried to implement an image. Maybe its generally caused by missing to implement the right property.

Answer (score 0):

If I nullcheck this.props.currentMeetingID I fix it, easy fix but nowhere to be found on the internet so I'll leave it here for anyone passing by. Probably me in a couple of weeks...